# How to debug Python script with IPython --pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pdb

I would like to debug an extension written for Sphinx in interactive mode using `pdb` which work great for simple scripts. When I execute `sphinx-build -M html . _build` I get an `ValueError`. So to debug it I wrote:

```
ipython3 $(which sphinx-build) --pdb -- -M html . _build
```

Unfortunately I don't get the full traceback, only the one from the main script `sphinx-build`:

```
$ ipython3 $(which sphinx-build) --pdb -- -M html . _build
Running Sphinx v3.1.2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 319, 
    in eval_config_file
    execfile_(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 88, 
    in execfile_
    exec(code, _globals)
  File "/home/canard/test-sphinx/conf.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/bin/sphinx-build in <module>()
      9 if __name__ == '__main__':
     10     sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
---> 11     sys.exit(main())

SystemExit: 2
> /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build(11)<module>()
      7 from sphinx.cmd.build import main
      8 
      9 if __name__ == '__main__':
     10     sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
---> 11     sys.exit(main())

ipdb>
```

How can I see the full traceback?

I tried to simplify the case by adding `raise ValueError()` into `conf.py`. So to reproduce just create a new sphinx project with `sphinx-quickstart`, modify `conf.py` and add the exception. With this setup you get the same issue. The debugger stops on `sys.exit(main())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RTFM](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFM) : from [the Sphinx manual](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/internals/contributing.html#debugging-tips) you may read:

> Debugging tips : Use the sphinx-build -P option to run pdb on exceptions.

This doesn't answer your question, but answers your [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)...